# React boostrap Table custom Cell doesn't render

Tags: customization, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap table and decided to customize a cell. My changes, however, do not render until I click into the cell. This is shown in the image below:

[Button doesn't render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Mo4.png)
[Button now renders now that I clicked into the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlMS.png)

My goal is to have the button render automatically in the cell.
I defined it as this:

```html
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField='knowledgeReference.0.docUrl'
                                       width="200px"
                                       hiddenOnInsert
                                       dataFormat={urlFormatter}
                                       tdStyle={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}}
                                       customEditor={ { getElement: createUrlEditor, customEditorParameters: {
                                           }} }>

                        Resource URL</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Has anyone seen an issue like this before? How did you resolve it?

Comment: What happened if you set state on componentDidMount() ?

Comment: I am unable to do that because that would require that I inherit from the Bootstrap Table class and override that function. Found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using **dataFormat** instead of customEditor. The bootstrap table doc doesn't clarify the distinction adequately.

```html
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='knowledgeReference'
                                       width="200px"
                                       editable={false}
                                       hiddenOnInsert
                                       dataFormat={urlFormatter}
                                       tdStyle={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}}
                                       dataFormat={createUrlEditor}
                    >

                        References</TableHeaderColumn>
```